# Sending NSMutableArray over custom url in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsurl

I am trying to send an NSMutableArray using custom URL. Below is the code to do send:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tempArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                      NULL,
                                                                                      (CFStringRef)jsonString,
                                                                                      NULL,
                                                                                      (CFStringRef)@"<>!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                      kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
```

I am able to send the encoded string in custom url and access it via [url query] followed by url decode. My problem is that I am able to get contents similar to what is in "jsonString" but afterwards I am not getting how to retrieve the array from it. Can someone guide to the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: " I am not getting how to retrieve the array from it".  What is "it"?  That seems like the more relevant code to show.

Comment: please post the response which you get